# Cisco IOS SHA-1 hash doesn't match

Tags: cisco, cisco-ios, cisco-asr

I download IOS from Cisco TAC and trying to load on ASR1006 but getting following error. I have compared bytes and they are same `671089864` on cisco TAC.

On Cisco TAC they have `MD5 hash` & `SHA512` but i am not seeing any `SHA-1` How do i validate its correct image?

```
Boot image size = 671089864 (0x280004c8) bytes

Missing or illegal ip address for variable DEFAULT_GATEWAY
Using midplane macaddr
Missing or illegal ip address for variable IP_ADDRESS
Missing or illegal ip address for variable IP_SUBNET_MASK
Package header rev 0 structure detected
Calculating SHA-1 hash...done
validate_package: SHA-1 hash:
    calculated ab6ca70a:a204b225:b6737d1a:219743dd:35a077b4
    expected   a2a1b227:5abeaabe:dca9b25f:0bdceb83:d213e622
SHA-1 hash doesn't match
boot: error executing "boot bootflash:asr1000rp2-adventerprisek9.03.16.03.S.155-3.S3-ext.bin"
```

## Update-1:

I did validate IOS and it generate correct md5sum, then why SHA-1 having issue?

```
verify /md5 (bootflash:asr1000rp2-adventerprisek9.03.16.03.S.155-3.S3-ext.bin) = 4093a0efb11f472c5d8f31e91cc0324f
```

## Update-2:

I have re-download new IOS and got same error, it is something else not IOS

Comment: Is this software suggested when entering the model number and serial of your router? I'd suggest opening a TAC case to confirm.

Comment: Yes! its suggested by `TAC` to upgrade. I did open cisco case

Comment: You are going to need to get Cisco TAC to fix this one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Solution:

Talked to Cisco TAC support and they found rommon (Firmware Version) has bug, and they upgrade following two component

```
R1#upgrade rom-monitor filename bootflash:asr1000-rommon-155-3r.S1.pkg R0

R1#upgrade rom-monitor filename bootflash:asr1000-rommon-155-3r.S1.pkg F0
```

Comment: You should accept your answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up and looking for an answer.

Comment: Yep, it is saying you have to wait for 2day...